# Does the regression model have to be the same as DAG?

Tags: modeling, causality, mediation, confounding, dag

I have built a DAG based on previous literature where a variable was used as a mediator in a paper and as a confounder in another paper. So, I used a bidirectional arrow between the exposure and the variable to explain the relationship in the DAG as mentioned in the literature. However, when running the logistic regression model, I adjusted for the variable and used it as a confounder and didn’t test for mediation.
I have received a comment saying that the regression model doesn’t support the claim in which this variable is a potential mediator and was in the causal pathway.

Do we have to build the regression model based on DAG and test for all associations?